# How to delete exact file from filesystem passing OS features?

Tags: file, memory, system, delete-file

I have:

- Installed OS with some filesystem as ext3 or ntfs or smth else
- exact file on this filesystem like Ozzy.mp3

I want:

- To delete this file passing OS and its features, but delete only this file with no corrupting other memory

How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean by "delete this file passing OS and its features" ?

Comment: it means not using syscalls/sysenters of kernel side of OS for file management

Answer (score 1):

If you want to erase a file bypassing the operating system entirely your program will need to include the code needed to update each file system's directory structures, for each file system you want to be compatible with.

I guess it may be kind of doable, but far from easy, and you'll end up with a rather bulky program (lots of code if you need to support several file systems).

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use OSes facilities for doing such things, you would need to:

- be running as a process with privileges to access drive device using MMIO or legacy IO ports (still needing to call OS syscalls to achieve this)
- write code to interact directly with device
- write filesystem driver
- find a way of noticing OS' filesystem driver that something has changed

The other way is to write OS stub for just manipulating the FS, but it really, really doesn't make sense, as there are such tools available.

---

To conclude: there is no point in doing it; if you need to bypass security facilities of filesystem, you have to either find a tool in the internet or give up (because, I assume you, you don't want to write even stub bare metal application to do this). This site is not meant to help people bypass security features.

Comment: it does really make sence, but on educational side of question, why do you assume me on not doing thing, really I want to learn and do?

Comment: @user1131997, you didn't give context of your question, like reason why do you want to do this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Ah, just checked your profile. Here we go. This question is definitely a step forward, comparing with that about `remove()`, but it's still not enough.

Comment: Reason: educational aims, cause I want to know how really OS does work, how really FS does work, how does it hold informartion ( what data structure: binary tree or smth else ), how can I get it bypassing OS, cause all the corners of questions projects on this aim.

The context was given as clear as it could, much more clearly it couldn't be given.

Comment: @user1131997, in your question there is "I want to remove it", not "I want to learn about FSes and stuff". For learning how does filesystem work, I would suggest reading, starting from various Wikipedia articles about the topic, and reading also excellent www.nobius.org/~dbg/practical-file-system-design.pdf. The way you've chosen is the worst possible way of learning things. Never look at it from "how to implement it?" perspective; rather try to find every possible piece of information in books, on Wikipedia and in technical documentations.

Comment: why is implementing is bad, if somebody does it, why can't you repeat step over step for better understanding, it's not even live practice , but non just knowladge, of you can implement and it gives the result and works, then your knowladge are perfect and programming skills too

Comment: @user1131997, it's bad just because you are completely helpless here. Get some higher level knowledge and only then move to lower level.